# Crash after Azure DevOps CI build succeeded

Tags: react-native, azure-devops

I have created an Azure DevOps Continuous Integration Pipeline for my React-Native Project. My Yaml is as below:

```yaml
pool:
  name: Azure Pipelines
  demands: yarn

steps:
- task: NodeTool@0
  displayName: 'Use Node 10.x'
  inputs:
    versionSpec: 10.x

- task: geeklearningio.gl-vsts-tasks-yarn.yarn-task.Yarn@3
  displayName: 'Install NPM modules'

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'clean '
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: ./android/gradlew
    arguments: clean
    workingDirectory: android

- task: Bash@3
  displayName: 'assembleRelease '
  inputs:
    targetType: filePath
    filePath: ./android/gradlew
    arguments: 'assembleRelease -x bundleReleaseJsAndAssets'
    workingDirectory: android

- task: PublishBuildArtifacts@1
  displayName: 'Publish Artifact: drop'
  inputs:
    PathtoPublish: android/app/build/outputs/apk/release
```

The build succeeded, but the problem is that the APK always crashes on the devices, but when I build the APK manually it does not crash.

Could any one help me?

Comment: Please let me know what is the device type the build crashes on

Comment: It was shaume redmi note 7

Comment: You can try  signing you apk with Android Signing task. For apk must be signed to run on a device. Please check out below answer.

Comment: @MemoralOreaalia Please add the crash error that you get from the phone. There are a multitude of things that can be happening. Maybe you have a missing class, or the app is not signed, or you are talking about debug/release. Or maybe you have a cached module locally that crashes when you do a clean build. So please attach the crash from 'adb logcat *:W' (or similar) and also add if this happens on installing the app or after running the app

Answer (score 2):

I see you didnot specify an agent vmImage to build your apk. You should specify the `vmImage` under the `pool` to let your apk be built on the desired OS. Since the apk built locally worked fine. You can specify an agent vmImage the same with you local machine.

```
pool:
  vmImage: windows-latest #or ubuntu-latest if your local machine is linux.
```

You can try using [gradle task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/gradle?view=azure-devops) to build your apk instead of using bash task. Unsigned APKs can only run in an emulator. APKs must be signed to run on a device. So after your apk is generated. you need to use [Android Signing task](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/azure/devops/pipelines/tasks/build/android-signing?view=azure-devops) to sign your apk in azure pipeline.

Please check [this](https://techcommunity.microsoft.com/t5/windows-dev-appconsult/using-azure-devops-to-create-a-ci-cd-pipeline-for-an-android/ba-p/1094422) detailed tutorial for more information.

In case the difference of jdk version causes the issue. You can compare the Jdk version used locally with the jdk version it used on your pipeline by checking the build task log. And make sure the jdk version used in azure pipeline is the same with your local jdk version by setting the `JDK version` field of gradle task.